# How exactly are the eye color genes related?

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, gene-expression

How exactly are the gey (maybe aka EYCL1?), bey(2?) (aka EYCL3?), HERC2, and OCA2 genes related to each other? There are numerous sources that explain eye color in terms of OCA2's role in the creation of melanin and the probable role of HERC2 in regulating its expression, and many Punnett squares invoking the gey and bey genes to explain inheritance (with the appropriate caveats regarding evidence of numerous other genes that also play lesser roles), but the relationship between the two is never really clarified.

Is the bey2 gene an alias for OCA2, or is it merely an unphysical phenotype that is likely coded (in part?) by OCA2 genotypes, or a pairing of specific HERC2 and OCA2 codings? What about gey?

Comment: There is polygenic inheritance of eye color as well.